# How to create segments from time periods

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have 2 activity types (TASK, CHAT). Each activity type has a priority with 10 being the highest priority.

I have the StartTime and EndTime of each activity.

I need to determine what activity the agent is actively working on at any given time. Where 2 activities overlap, the activity with the highest priority is considered to be the activity the agent is working on.

My initial thoughts of tackling this problem is to break the activity times into segments based on the StartTime and EndTime as well as time the activities overlap. Then for each segment taking the activity with the highest priority.

For example: 09:00-09:15 (CHAT), 09:15-09:30 (CHAT), 09:30-09:45 (TASK)

However, I really have no idea how to go about achieving this in SQL.
I've done some research on 'Gaps and Islands' but I haven't found any examples that I can translate into solving this problem.

I am wondering if anyone is able to give me advice as to the best approach to this problem and a possible solution so that I can understand the solution and implement it?

**MY DATA**

```
DECLARE @ActivityLog TABLE (Activity VARCHAR(4), Priority INT, StartTime DATETIME, EndTime DATETIME)

INSERT INTO @ActivityLog VALUES ('CHAT', 10, '2019/07/01 09:00', '2019/07/01 09:30') INSERT INTO @ActivityLog VALUES ('TASK', 5, '2019/07/01 09:15', '2019/07/01 09:45')

SELECT * FROM @ActivityLog
```

**Expected final output**

```
+------------------+------------------+----------+
|     StartTime    |      EndTime     | Activity |
+------------------+------------------+----------+
| 2019/07/01 09:00 | 2019/07/01 09:15 |   CHAT   |
+------------------+------------------+----------+
| 2019/07/01 09:15 | 2019/07/01 09:30 |   CHAT   |
+------------------+------------------+----------+
| 2019/07/01 09:30 | 2019/07/01 09:45 |   TASK   |
+------------------+------------------+----------+
```

**Scenario 2**
TASK has an active segment before and after the CHAT.

```
DECLARE @ActivityLog TABLE (Activity VARCHAR(8), Priority INT, StartTime DATETIME, EndTime DATETIME)

INSERT INTO @ActivityLog VALUES ('TASK', 7, '2019/07/01 09:00', '2019/07/01 10:00')
INSERT INTO @ActivityLog VALUES ('CHAT', 10, '2019/07/01 09:15', '2019/07/01 09:45');
```

**Scenario 2 Expected Output**

```
+------------------+------------------+----------+
|     StartTime    |      EndTime     | Activity |
+------------------+------------------+----------+
| 2019/07/01 09:00 | 2019/07/01 09:15 |   TASK   |
+------------------+------------------+----------+
| 2019/07/01 09:15 | 2019/07/01 09:45 |   CHAT   |
+------------------+------------------+----------+
| 2019/07/01 09:45 | 2019/07/01 10:00 |   TASK   |
+------------------+------------------+----------+
```

Comment: is the start and end time for the activity always in 15 mins lot ? If it does not, then how would that show in the expected output ?

Comment: Hi @Squirrel it will not always be in 15 min intervals. This would show in expected output similar to how it is above however the minutes would show the respective start/end time. For example 09:01 start and 09:11 end followed by 09:11 start and 10:27 end (if that was what the activity times were).

Comment: based on your last example, how would the expected result looks like ? Can you update that in your sample data and expected result ?

Comment: Hi @Squirrel I have used 15 minute intervals in the example data for simplicity however the start and end time of the activity can occur at any time as it is dependent upon the time the agent starts/stops the activity.

Comment: @J.Bradow The second scenario - why CHAT time is expanded from `15 to 30` to `15 to 45`?

Comment: @gotqn This is an error on my end. I will edit the question and fix this now :)

Answer (score 1):

The following is working when we have maximum of two overlapping periods (if you need more, you need to change the code to use recursive common table expression).

The idea is to get overlaps using `LEFT JOIN` and then to apply different logic depending on the priority of the items.

It is simple, but ugly. I have added few more cases and tests, and hope that did not miss anything.

```
DECLARE @ActivityLog TABLE (Activity VARCHAR(4), Priority INT, StartTime DATETIME, EndTime DATETIME)

INSERT INTO @ActivityLog 
VALUES ('CHAT', 10, '2019/07/01 09:00', '2019/07/01 09:30') 
      ,('TASK', 5, '2019/07/01 09:15', '2019/07/01 09:20')
      --
      ,('CHAT', 8, '2019/07/01 19:30', '2019/07/01 20:30')
      --
      ,('TASK', 7, '2019/07/02 09:00', '2019/07/02 10:00')
      ,('CHAT', 10, '2019/07/02 09:15', '2019/07/02 09:30')
      --
      ,('CHAT', 10, '2019/12/01 09:00', '2019/12/01 09:30') 
      ,('TASK', 5, '2019/12/01 09:15', '2019/12/01 09:20');


WITH DataSourceWithRowID AS
(
    SELECT *
         ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [StartTime]) AS [row_id]
    FROM @ActivityLog
),
DataSource AS
(
    SELECT S.[Activity] AS [S_Activity], S.[Priority] AS [S_Priority], S.[StartTime] AS [S_StartTime], S.[EndTime] AS [S_EndTime], S.[row_id] AS [S_row_id]
          ,E.[Activity] AS [E_Activity], E.[Priority] AS [E_Priority], E.[StartTime] AS [E_StartTime], E.[EndTime] AS [E_EndTime], E.[row_id] AS [E_row_id]
    FROM DataSourceWithRowID S
    LEFT JOIN DataSourceWithRowID E
        ON E.[StartTime] > S.[StartTime] 
        AND E.[StartTime] < S.[EndTime]
)
-- case 1 - handle 1
SELECT [S_Activity], [S_Priority], [S_StartTime], [E_StartTime]
FROM DataSource
WHERE S_Priority > E_Priority
    AND S_EndTime < E_EndTime

UNION ALL

-- case 1 - handle 2
SELECT [S_Activity], [S_Priority], [E_StartTime], [S_EndTime]
FROM DataSource
WHERE S_Priority > E_Priority
    AND S_EndTime < E_EndTime

UNION ALL

-- case 1 - handle 3
SELECT [E_Activity], [E_Priority], [S_EndTime], [E_EndTime]
FROM DataSource
WHERE S_Priority > E_Priority
    AND S_EndTime < E_EndTime

UNION ALL

-- case 1 - handle 4 -- sub period with low priorty -> consume by parent
SELECT [S_Activity], [S_Priority], [S_StartTime], [S_EndTime]
FROM DataSource
WHERE S_Priority > E_Priority
    AND S_EndTime > E_EndTime

UNION ALL

-- case 2 - no overlapping
SELECT [S_Activity], [S_Priority], [S_StartTime], [S_StartTime]
FROM DataSource
WHERE [S_row_id] NOT IN (SELECT [E_row_id] FROM DataSource WHERE [E_row_id] IS NOT NULL)
    AND [E_row_id] IS NULL

UNION ALL

-- case 3 - handle 1
SELECT S_Activity, S_Priority, S_StartTime, E_StartTime
FROM DataSource 
WHERE S_Priority < E_Priority

UNION ALL

-- case 3 - handle 2
SELECT  E_Activity
       ,E_Priority
       ,E_StartTime
       ,IIF(S_EndTime > E_EndTime,  E_EndTime, S_EndTime)
FROM DataSource 
WHERE S_Priority < E_Priority

UNION ALL

-- case 3 - handle 3
SELECT IIF(S_EndTime > E_EndTime,  S_Activity, E_Activity)
      ,IIF(S_EndTime > E_EndTime,  S_Priority, E_Priority)
      ,IIF(S_EndTime > E_EndTime,  E_EndTime, S_EndTime)
      ,IIF(S_EndTime > E_EndTime,  S_EndTime, E_EndTime)       
FROM DataSource 
WHERE S_Priority < E_Priority
```

Comment: Hi @gotqn I have tested this with the following data and it fails to return the expected results: ('TASK', 7, '2019/07/01 09:00', '2019/07/01 10:00')
('CHAT', 10, '2019/07/01 09:00', '2019/07/01 09:45')